# To reverse sentence in python

Tags: python, loops, indexing

Thank you for all the answers. I got why my code is wrong.

Please don't provide me with solutions because I do have a few but then I want to understand my code is not working.

I think it is due to `while x <= -len(split_result):"` but then the I think the logic is correct. What is wrong with my code?

```
O_string = ("Me name is Mr_T")
split_result = O_string.split()
print(split_result)

x=0
list=[]

while x <= -len(split_result):
    list.append(split_result[x-1])
    x = x-1

result=" ".join(list)
print (result)
```

Comment: `' '.join('Hello world'.split()[::-1])`

Comment: You're checking if `x` is less than or equal to a negative value after initialising as `x=0`, so you'll never enter your `while` loop

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of a question asking how to reverse the order of *characters* in a *string*. However, this question is different: it's asking how to reverse the order of *words* (separated by a space character) in a *sentence*.

Answer (score 8):

You can reverse a list with `[::-1]`:

```
print(' '.join(O_string.split()[::-1]))
```

Output:

```
'Mr_T is name Me'
```

Here `[::-1]` means take everything from the beginning to the end with a step size of minus one.

Alternatively, you can use the built-in function `reversed`:

```
>>> ' '.join(reversed(O_string.split()))
'Mr_T is name Me'
```

About your algorithm. In my opinion it is always more difficult to think in negative indices. I would suggest to go positive:

```
O_string = ("Me name is Mr_T")
split_result = O_string.split()

res = []
x = len(split_result) - 1
while x >= 0:
    res.append(split_result[x])
    x = x-1

result=" ".join(res)
print (result)
```

Output:

```
'Mr_T is name Me'
```

Here:

```
x = len(split_result) - 1
```

gives you the last index of your list. We start indexing with `0`. So you need to subtract `1` from the length of the list.

You count it down with:

```
x = x-1
```

and stop as soon as you get a negative index:

```
while x >= 0:
```

**Hint**: Don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a built-in and should better not be used for naming own objects. If you do, you cannot easily use `list()` anymore (in the same namespace).

Answer (score 1):

can make use of the reverse function as well as str.join

```
O_string = ("Me name is Mr_T")
split_result = O_string.split()
split_result.reverse()
print " ".join(split_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, `list[::-1]` will give you the list in which all the elements of the list stored in reverse index position. ie.) `reverseList1=list1[::-1]` use this.

Answer (score 1):

To answer "What is wrong with my code?", let's look at what happens in a shell:

```
>>> O_string = ("Me name is Mr_T")
split_result = O_string.split()
print(split_result)
['Me', 'name', 'is', 'Mr_T']
>>> x=0
>>> len(split_result)
4
>>> -len(split_result)
-4
>>> x
0
>>> 0 <= 4
True
>>> 0 <= -4
False
>>> x <= -len(split_result)
False
>>> while False: print('this will not get printed')
```

So, your while loop condition will never be true and the loop will never happen. Here is an example of what works:

```
x = -1
while x >= -len(split_result):
    list.append(split_result[x])
```

Comment: Say I set x = 0 at the start,

Comment: @Alexis well then you have to make other adjustments to compensate: `x >= -len(split_result) + 1` and `split_result[x-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> O_string = ("Me name is Mr_T")
>>> O_list = O_string.split()
>>> O_list.reverse()
>>> " ".join(O_list)
'Mr_T is name Me'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reversed to reverse the sentence:

```
o_string = "Me name is Mr_T"
words = sentence.split()
o_string = " ".join(reversed(words))
print(o_string)
```